# How to make Unbound block private IPs in resolved domains (DNS rebinding)

Tags: domain-name-system, private-ip, unbound

I set up Unbound in my local network as a local DNS resolver. I noticed that it will not filter any private IP addresses in the resolved domains and forward any IP address that a domain resolves to.

In order to protect against DNS rebinding, I would like to make Unbound not return any private IP addresses from public domains to the clients, however I haven't found any information on that from the official documentation. Apparently dnsmasq does this protection by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is called `private-address:` in Unbound.  See [this document](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/) and look for "private-address: "

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. This solves my question, thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I miss things all the time :-)

Comment: I would like to add that it is required to add the `private-address` option multiple times for multiple networks, as it is explained for `private-domain` right below. ;-)